# Xcode UISearchBar Code Implementation

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uisearchbar

I'm currently working on a project where I have to filter through a NSArray (displayed in an UITableView). Problem is, there is neither a XIB file nor a storyboard.
My question is (I already got the predicate and search method et.c set up), how do I get the SearchBar to show up in my program only using code - and ofc I need to be able to work with it.
I'd be really glad about some help with this issue, because every tutorial I found either uses storyboards or xibs :(

Thank you very much up front!
Btw those are the two methods I got so far concerning the search bar, the TableView is also set up already.

```
-(void) filterContentForSearchText:(NSString *)searchText scope:(NSString *)scope {
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@", searchText];
self.searchResults = [self.array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

}

```
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString  {
[self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
return YES;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

In your .h add this:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) UISearchBar *searchBar;
```

Add this in your `viewDidLoad` method

```
self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]init];
self.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
self.searchBar.delegate = self;
//Customize the searchBar
[self.view addSubview:self.searchBar];
```

And whenever you want to search, press the search button within the keyboard. A delegate will be called when you do this. Like so,

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
  [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
  //Do some search
}
```

You can access the entered the text using the `searchBar.text` property. I am assuming that you have implemented the relevant protocols.

Comment: Tried this, but I get a warning at self.searchBar.delegate = self saying "Assining to id... from incompatible type" and an error at self.view addSubview saying "No visible @Interface for UIView", any ideas?

Comment: `@interface ViewController () <UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate>` This should solve the issue. :)

It's `addSubview` not `addSubView`.

Comment: Mhh at least the Search Bar shows up now ;) The problem now is though that 1) the Keyboard does not disappear as it should
2) Grey Screen overlays some of my TableView, then the Search bar, and then Grey Screen again. I'm not sure what happens here... Do you know how to solve this follow up ? ;)

Comment: I do. But I might need to see some more code as to know what is really going on.

Comment: Damn since I'm just a student at a company I'm not allowed to post big parts of the code online, could you tell me which parts of the code you need? That would be great, thanks!

Comment: Okay. Here is the deal. If you have copy pasted my code, it will occupy the WHOLE area of the screen. And that's bad. `CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);`. Change this code to something more practical;`CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 20)`

The `[searchBar resignFirstResponder]` method is responsible for hiding he keyboard. Use that method wherever you want to hide the keyboard. :)

Comment: Ah thank you very much!!! I will try this, but that doesn't change that the search bar is overlaying parts of the table view (even if it's just the first row), how do I need to change this method 
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
to resize the table view smaller than the screen?

Comment: Start the `tableView` where `searchBar` ends! You can do so by setting the frame of the `tableView` to something like:
`tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0,self.searchBar.frame.size.height,100,100)` or whatever the height and width of your tableView.
Okay, I have answered a lot. -_- :P

Comment: Yes, and I think that solves my problem! I'd give you votes up but since I'm new here I can't. Anyways, I really appreciate your help, have a great day and thank you very much ;)

Answer (score 0):

If there is no XIB file and no Storyboard, it is initiated somewhere in the code (probably in the viewDidload) looking something like this.

```
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 20)];
searchBar.delegate = self;
//etc..
```

Now first add a property in the interface

```
@property (nonatomic, strong)UISearchBar *searchBar;
```

And change this line in the viewDidLoad:

```
self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 20)];
```

Now you can us `self.searchBar` anywhere in your code.

Edit:

And don't forget to add this to the interface if it wasn't already:

```
@interface ViewController () <UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate>
```

Comment: I tried your method as well, and got no errors or warnings so this should've worked but it did not appear on the screen. I found this method:   
' 
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
} ' 
Do I need to change something here?

Comment: Your method worked now, It needed [self.view addSubview:self.searchBar]; to actually show up, unfortunately it's overlaying some of the TableView, could you help me out there as well please?